# What is the pandas equivalent of R's qnorm()

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I am moving some code from R to Anaconda Python. The R code uses `qnorm`, documented as "quantile function for the normal distribution with mean equal to `mean` and standard deviation equal to `sd`."

The call and parameters are:

> ```
>    qnorm(p, mean = 0, sd = 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
>    p           vector of probabilities.
>    mean        vector of means.
>    sd          vector of standard deviations.
>    log.p       logical; if TRUE, probabilities p are given as log(p).
>    lower.tail  logical; if TRUE (default), probabilities are
>                             P[X≤x] otherwise, P[X].
> ```

I don't see any equivalent in pandas.Series.  Have I missed it, is it on another object, or is there some equivalent in another library?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A lot of this equivalent functionality is found in [scipy.stats](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html). In this case, you're looking for [`scipy.stats.norm.ppf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html#scipy-stats-norm).

`qnorm(p, mean = 0, sd = 1)` is equivalent to `scipy.stats.norm.ppf(q, loc=0, scale=1)`.

---

```
import scipy.stats as st

>>> st.norm.ppf([0.01, 0.99])
array([-2.32634787,  2.32634787])

>>> st.norm.ppf([0.01, 0.99], loc=10, scale=0.1)
array([  9.76736521,  10.23263479])
```

Comment: How do I get `lower.tail=FALSE?` Thanks :)

Comment: @TheUnfunCat I'm guessing you just mean `st.norm.ppf(0.99)`?

Comment: No, R has an argument lower.tail to qnorm that makes the results slightly different. Sorry for being imprecise in my first q :)

Comment: oh wait, `qnorm(0.1)` is the same as `qnorm(.9, lower.tail=FALSE)`

Comment: No worries - yep, the lower tail argument just specifies whether you are taking the left or right tail probability..

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand @miradulo answer. If you want to get also `qnorm(lower.tail=FALSE)` you can just multiply by -1:

In R:

```
qnorm(0.8, lower.tail = F)
-0.8416212
```

In python

```
from scipy.stats import norm

norm.ppf(0.8) * -1
-0.8416212
```